# An issue with IDictionary in Asp Net Core uri parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an endpoint that is declared this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks([FromQuery] IDictionary<string, string> processVariables, string orderBy = "created:asc")
```

When I trigger it with query */api/v1/usertasks?orderBy=created%3Aasc* the string `created:asc` occurs in both `processVariables` and `orderBy` parameters:

[image]

Basically Asp Net Core engine treats this value both as a dictionary key-value and as a parameter named `orderBy`. Is there a way to make `created:asc` value to be resolved only as `orderBy` parameter?

Otherwise, what would be the best way to organize this endpoint, so it has a dictionary parameter and a string parameter with a default value?

This happens in Asp Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using the following endpoint signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks([FromQuery] ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> processVariables, string orderBy = "created:asc")
```

The endpoint should be called using this url:

`/api/v1/usertasks?processVariables[0].Key=1&processVariables[0].Value=2&orderBy=created%3Aasc`

This way even if the **processVariables** are not provided all endpoint parameters are filled correctly

Answer (score 1):

You are passing only the optional parameter Orderby on your query string.

```
/api/v1/usertasks?orderBy=created%3Aasc
```

By convention, if you have a dictionary it will fill
"whatever string & whatever string" in the key-value and you will end never getting on your optional parameter.

To proper use your dictionary you need to do:

```
/api/v1/usertasks?processVariables[0]=firstString&processVariables[1]=secondString&orderBy=created%3Aasc
```

PS: Using Dictionary on an endpoint will break your swagger doc

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a model includes a model which contains `IDictionary<string, string> processVariables` and `string orderBy = "created:asc"`,so that orderBy=created%3Aasc will not be binded to `processVariables`.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class DictionaryModel
    {
        public string orderBy { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> processVariables { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks(DictionaryModel d)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]